# Wordpress SQL_CALC fix causes PHP error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm looking for some followup on an older topic for Wordpress where SQL_CALC was found to slow things down when you have a large DB in Wordpress. I have been using the code, at the bottom of this post, to get around it but it does generate an error in my error log. How would I prevent this error?

```
 PHP Warning:  Division by zero in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/greatTheme/functions.php on line 19
```

The original thread:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/slow-queries-sql_calc_found_rows-bringing-down-site?replies=25

The code in my functions.php:

```
 add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'optimized_get_posts', 100);
 function optimized_get_posts() {
    global $wp_query, $wpdb;

    $wp_query->query_vars['no_found_rows'] = 1;
    $wp_query->found_posts = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')" );
    $wp_query->found_posts = apply_filters_ref_array( 'found_posts', array( $wp_query->found_posts, &$wp_query ) );
    $wp_query->max_num_pages = ceil($wp_query->found_posts / $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page']);

    return $wp_query;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Daan's suggestion, I tried the following and it hasn't produced any errors:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'optimized_get_posts', 100);
function optimized_get_posts() {
    global $wp_query, $wpdb;
    $wp_query->query_vars['no_found_rows'] = 1;
    $wp_query->found_posts = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')" );
    $wp_query->found_posts = apply_filters_ref_array( 'found_posts', array( $wp_query->found_posts, &$wp_query ) );
    if($wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] <= 0) {
        $wp_query->max_num_pages = 0;
    } else {
        $wp_query->max_num_pages = ceil($wp_query->found_posts / $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page']);
    }
    return $wp_query;
}
```

Basically, the code checks to see if `$wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page']` has a positive value and would therefore be able to divide `$wp_query->found_posts` appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably `$wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page']` is set to 0, which means you are asking PHP to divide `$wp_query->found_posts` by zero. Of course, this cannot be done. I don't know where in your code this var is being set (is WP handling this?) but it's easy to confirm this by adding an `print_r $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'];` before that line.